# SQL Query to update the value of column of one table based on condition on two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-update

I have three tables :

```
INDICATOR
---------------------   
 ID  | INDICATOR_NEW
---------------------
 001 | 1
 002 | 1
 003 | 1


DETAILS
------------------------
 ID  | ADD  | POSTDATE
------------------------
 001 | ADD1 | 02-AUG-15    
 001 | ADD2 | 09-AUG-15
 002 | ADD1 | 09-AUG-15    
 002 | ADD2 | 02-AUG-15


HISTORY
--------------------------------
 ID  | ADD  | STARTDATE | VALUE
--------------------------------
 001 | ADD1 | 02-AUG-15 | 100        
 001 | ADD2 | 09-AUG-15 | 10        
 002 | ADD1 | 09-AUG-15 | 20        
 002 | ADD2 | 02-AUG-15 | 25
```

I have to write a SQL code to update the `INDICATOR_NEW` value of `INDICATOR` table to 0 based on the following checks :

1. `ID` of `INDICATOR` table exists in `DETAILS` table.
2. Record for the above id exists in `HISTORY` table and for that `ID` holds `HISTORY.MAX(STARTDATE) = DETAILS.POSTDATE - 7`

I am trying to obtain the result with the following query:

```
 UPDATE INDICATOR
    SET INDICATOR_NEW = 0
  WHERE INDICATOR_NEW = 1
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM DETAILS D1
                WHERE ID = D1.ID)
   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                 from (SELECT MAX(STARTDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) RN,ID
                         from HISTORY H1)T1,
                      DETAILS D1
                WHERE T1.RN = D1.DMDPOSTDATE - 7
                 AND T1.ID = D1.ID);
```

Is this the correct way of obtaining the desired result or should I use `GROUP BY` instead of `PARTITION BY`(considering performance efficiency)?

Comment: If its is T-SQL (decide you use mysql/orace/sqlserver) tag, you can definitely simplify first part to `UPDATE  INDICATOR
  SET INDICATOR_NEW = 0
  FROM INDICATOR i
  JOIN DETAILS D1
      ON i.ID = D1.ID
 ...`

Comment: Thanks.So will it improve the performance of code.? ? Also can u suggest on the second part ??

Comment: If you prepare structures, sample data and share link using [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Don't tag questions with multiple databases unless you need to solution to work with all (and if so that should be indicated in the question), it's just confusing as different databases use different syntax, so an answer written for MSSQL for instance wouldn't work with MySQL etcetera. Just include the db you are actually using.

Comment: I want answer for my sql.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- You should use an alias for `indicator` let say `I`
- First `exists`, I guess you mean `I.ID = D1.ID`
- Second `exists`, I don't see you use outer table, so the result will be always the same. Also have carefull because I think that query will always return a value anyway.
- For this case `group by` will give you same result.

.

```
UPDATE  INDICATOR I -- include alias
SET INDICATOR_NEW = 0
WHERE 
    INDICATOR_NEW = 1
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM DETAILS D1
     WHERE ID = D1.ID) -- use I.ID if that is the case
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM (SELECT H1.ID, MAX(H1.STARTDATE) RN
           FROM HISTORY H1
           GROUP BY H1.ID
          )T1 , DETAILS D1
     WHERE T1.RN = D1.DMDPOSTDATE - 7
     AND   T1.ID = D1.ID  -- here you aren't using outer table so always same result
  )
```

Comment: So performance wise GROUP BY is better to use here instead of PARTITION BY ?

Comment: I'm not sure, you will have to perform analyze to compare. My guess is probably the same. But `group by` is easy to read for me.

Comment: Hi Juan.. thanks for your help. But can you modify the code above so that the value in INDICATOR table gets updated only if it exists in DETAILS and HISTORY table and MAX(HISTORY.STARTDATE) = DETAILS.DMDPOSTDATE - 7

Comment: Your help is much appreciated Juan. :)

Comment: I don't mind helping. But the best way of ask this type of question is show your schema, provide some input data and your desire result. You have  first two still need desire output. You could modifiy your question and let me know. Also help if you provide a [**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ed95/15), that way I can provide a working solution

Comment: Please include the desire output with that data.

Comment: You dont need comment multiple times. I will help you when I have time to read all that you write. And please next time just update your question instead of putting code in comment, because you can do a better format there. Just leave a small comment with `@user_name` so user get a notification you update your question.